# H264 keyframe issue with RTP

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, rtp, encoder

I'm building an RTP encoder for H264 video.  The video data provider doesn't periodically stream the keyframe in the data, instead they have provided me with a binary file representation of the keyframe.  This includes the SPS-PPS-SEI and then 8 slices of the i-frame.

Since I am encoding RTP, I need to rebroadcast this keyframe at 2 second intervals.  I am doing that in my code, along with the rest of the data as it comes in.  I am using ffmpeg to connect to the RTP data via a UDP socket for display testing.

I am noticing that every 2 seconds, the video seems to blank and resync itself, pixelate, etc.  Obviously, this is highly undesirable in the video product.  I've been trying to debug this for quite some time and the only thing I can determine is that it has to do with the keyframe.  If I just send the keyframe once, and then the rest of the data, ffmpeg displays the video fine.  But in a network environment, I need to send the keyframe at periodic intervals.

Does anyone have an idea as to why this resyncing of the video happens and most importantly, how to stop it from happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SPS, PPS and SEI are needed to setup the decoder and fall under the [non-VCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Abstraction_Layer#VCL_and_Non-VCL_NAL_Units) data. These are typically found in the stream before the IDR-frame, but they can also be communicated out of band e.g. via SDP. If you have no out-of-band mechanism for communicating the SPS, and PPS, then sure, you'll need to periodically resend them in-band so that new clients can initialise the H.264 decoder.

> I am noticing that every 2 seconds, the video seems to blank and resync itself, pixelate, etc. Obviously, this is highly undesirable in the video product. I've been trying to debug this for quite some time and the only thing I can determine is that it has to do with the keyframe. If I just send the keyframe once, and then the rest of the data, ffmpeg displays the video fine. But in a network environment, I need to send the keyframe at periodic intervals.

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but you can not resend the "static" i-frame (probably an IDR) data every two seconds: you are sending "old" previously decoded VCL data to the encoder which has the effect of re-syncing the stream.

> Does anyone have an idea as to why this resyncing of the video happens and most importantly, how to stop it from happening?

Try sending only the non-VCL NAL units periodically. You can either do this periodically, or you can prepend them only to IDR-frames in the stream, since you can only start playing back a video (without artifacts) at this point anyway.
.

Comment: Thank you very much for your well written explanation.  Just so I am clear in my understanding - the "i-frame" is actually the group of IDR packets, NOT the SPS/PPS/SEI along with the IDR packets, correct?  I was assuming it was this complete access unit that made the i-frame.

Comment: The SPS/PPS/SEI are considered part of the same Access Unit. The term "i-frame" is not applicable in H.264 where an IDR is a special AU consisting of i-slices, and by definition no frames after the IDR are predicted from frames before the IDR.